# How to create numbers with rounded background in UITableViewCell (like the email app)?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In the email app, on the overview page, you can see a summary of the number of new emails you have in your accounts. Does anyone know how to create the numbers on the rounded background?

[image: email summary]

Comment: +1 Good question, I'm interested to hear the answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a built-in cell style but should be pretty easy to mimic.

Add a `UILabel` to the cell set its `font`, `textColor` and `backgroundColor`. To get the rounded corners, play with `label.layer.cornerRadius`.

Answer (score 4):

If you read this post on TUAW, you can get more infos about your problem...
http://www.tuaw.com/2010/01/07/iphone-devsugar-simple-table-badges/

Tim Grant Davies created an open source project to do what you want and it is available under CC License on github... You can download it here: https://github.com/tmdvs/TDBadgedCell

Hope this can help you :)

Comment: When I used this class I ran into memory issues. Did some searching online and found that some other folks ran into the same issues.